# R: alternative for logical selection using select()

Tags: r, select, dplyr

I'd like to select all rows in a dataset except for those that take place in the years 2010 and 2020.

This is what I'm trying

```
by_year <- df %>% 
  select(Year != c(2010, 2020)) %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise(mean(df))
```

This is the error I get

```
Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
  no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

I'm aware it is because I'm using !=

What alternative do I have to specify which years I wouldn't like to be selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `filter` instead of `select` as `select` is for selecting column while `filter` filters out or keep the rows based on the expression.  For more than one element, `==` will not work as it is elementwise comparison operator, so either the `rhs` of `==` needs to be of `length` 1 or another column or vector of the same length as the lhs.  If that is not the case, use `%in%` and negate (`!`), then we do a group by and `summarise` by getting the `mean` `across` the numeric columns

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(!Year %in%  c(2010, 2020)) %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Why can't we simply do  summarise(mean(df))

Comment: @Joehat i assume `df` is the data.frame object. and you want to sum each of the columns of the data 'df' grouped by 'Year'.  Most of the functions work on a vector or a column instead of a data.frame

Comment: In the opposite case of me wanting to filter by those years I tried filter(Year %in%  c("2010", "2020")) but it doesn't seem to work as object Year is not found (it's inside the pipe).

Comment: @Joehat Have you used `df %>%filter(Year %in% c("2010", "2020"))` because the `data` is the first argument and with `%>%`, it is passed on from the lhs.  If you are using standalone `filter`, then it would be `filter(df, Year %in% c(2010, 2020))`

Comment: Yeah, I was using that structure. Just wanted to confirm if simply by removing ! the opposite could be done. I'll figure out what might be going on. Thanks for your clarifications!